# How do I use an NPM package in a vanilla HTML/CSS/JS project?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm

I have a simple website built with `HTML`, `CSS`, and some `in-line JS`. I want to be able to use this `NPM` package [Simple MDE Markdown Editor](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor), but I don't know how. I tried running `npm install simplemde --save` in my project directory. That created a `node_modules` folder with the `NPM` package inside it, but how do I import that into my project? If I just try to use the package without importing it in any way, I get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SimpleMDE is not defined.

Comment: I'd prefer including it from a CDN. If you go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplemde in Install section, the last code snippet is loading from CDN.

Comment: Please go through the readme.md file in that repository. you can use the package via `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `node_modules` requires tools like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).
If your project is fully vanilla, you can try to add the [cdn](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor#install) (I guess you need the links below), should work as npm module.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>
```